# how can we accept request body with multiparts?

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload, postman, multipartform-data

I am trying to make post request with request body and four multipart files.

I have shared the api

```
@PostMapping(value = "/deductee-master", consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity <DeducteeMaster> createDeductee(@RequestBody DeducteeMasterDTO deducteeMasterDTO, @RequestParam("trcFile") MultipartFile trcFile, @RequestParam("tenFFile") MultipartFile tenFFile, @RequestParam("wpeFile") MultipartFile wpeFile, @RequestParam("noPEFile") MultipartFile noPEFile)
throws InvalidKeyException, URISyntaxException, StorageException, IOException {
    DeducteeMaster result = deducteeMasterService.save(deducteeMasterDTO, trcFile, tenFFile, wpeFile, noPEFile);
    return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/deductee-master/" + result.getKey().getId()))
        .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(ENTITY_NAME, result.getKey().getId().toString()))
        .body(result);
}
```

> ```
> {
>     "timestamp": "2019-06-24T11:04:40.076+0000",
>     "status": 415,
>     "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
>     "message": "Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------603218794646006873131102;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
>     "path": "/api/deductee-master"
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@RequestPart`, and also since you are trying to send both `RequestBody` and `Files` you have to append it to the FormData to send the data.

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public ResponseEntity<DeducteeMaster> createDeductee(@RequestPart("data") DeducteeMasterDTO deducteeMasterDTO,
            @RequestPart("trcFile") MultipartFile trcFile,
            @RequestPart("tenFFile") MultipartFile tenFFile,
            @RequestPart("wpeFile") MultipartFile wpeFile,
            @RequestPart("noPEFile") MultipartFile noPEFile)
            throws InvalidKeyException, URISyntaxException, StorageException, IOException {

     //LOGIC
     return // ...;

    }
```

In case you want to test using CurL

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" 
             -F "data =@test.json;type=application/json" 
             -F "trcFile =@test.csv;type=application/csv"
             -F "tenFFile =@test1.csv;type=application/csv"
             -F "wpeFile =@test2.csv;type=application/csv"
             -F "noPEFile =@test3.csv;type=application/csv"
             http://localhost:8080/foo
```

If you are sending post request through Angular, React or any javascript lang try using FormData.Append the data to formData

Comment: actually i have around 35 fields of data in dto along with these four multiparts how i can accept data and multipart both.

Comment: For testing i am using swagger.

Comment: ```curl -i -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" -F "deducteeMasterDTO =@realpath(C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\data.json");type=application/json" -F "trcFile =@realpath(C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\CognitiveComplexity.pdf);type=application/pdf" -F "tenFFile =@realpath(C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\CognitiveComplexity.pdf);type=application/pdf" -F "wpeFile =@realpath(C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\CognitiveComplexity.pdf);type=application/pdf" -F "noPEFile =@realpath(C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\CognitiveComplexity.pdf);type=application/pdf" http://localhost:8080/api/deductee-master```

Comment: i am facing issue:: ```curl: (3) Port number ended with '\'
curl: (3) Port number ended with '\'
curl: (3) Port number ended with '\'
curl: (3) Port number ended with '\'```

Comment: the problem is with the '\', can you remove the `@realPath`  and also go to the Desktop directory in `CMD` and just try with `deducteeMasterDTO=@data.json;type=application/json` do the same for other data